# VB Me.Controls.Remove(.........) not working with any component

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently trying to make a Picture box (Player) interact with a Collectable (Diamond1) and remove the collectable using Me.Controls.Remove(Diamond1).

For some reason, this doesn't work, no matter what I replace Diamond1 with.

I also tried Me.Controls.Clear() to test if the controls would work. This did work.

This is the code below ---

```
Private Sub DiamondInteraction()
    If Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Diamond1.Bounds) Then
        PlayerScore = PlayerScore + DiamondValue
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
        Me.Controls.Remove(Diamond1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the Diamond1 control directly inside the form? Or is it in a different container?

Comment: Diamond1 is in Form1, on a panel

Comment: Then you need to do `Me.Panel.Controls.Remove(Diamond1)`

Comment: Or better yet, `Diamond1.Parent.Controls.Remove(Diamond1)`

Comment: Thank you. If you post as a reply I'll give you a positive to improve your reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Control.Remove` method should be called on the control which *directly* contains the control to be removed. If the control is directly on the form, you can do `Me.Controls.Remove(Diamond1)`. But if it is in a container such as a panel, you should do `Panel1.Controls.Remove(Diamond1)`.

However, this method will get whatever the parent is (if you don't know it).

```
Private Sub RemoveControl(c As Control)
    c.Parent.Controls.Remove(c)
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
RemoveControl(Diamond1)
```

Comment: Good thinking using `Parent.Remove()`!